# application fabric metaphor azure

Tags: azure

Could anyone provide a  simple metaphor for understanding application fabric in windows azure.
For example if you would like this to be explained to average students so it is easy for them to remember.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking about AppFabric? I think that brand has gone away. It used to encompass Service Bus and the Caching service.